# Possible C++ 17 compiler version Problem "is not a member of ‘std’"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Trying to build my code with cmake configuration as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(filemanager)

set(DEBUG_MODE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options("-m32")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-m32 -std=c++17")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-m32")
```

I am getting an error in a function:

```
error: 'scoped_lock' is not a member of 'std'
```

My code summary looks like this:

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

int GetRequestId()
{
    std::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

My OS Ubuntu 16.04. My cmake outputs this:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

***EDIT*** They say it is a compiler version problem. I installed gcc-7 g++-7 and give priority as follows:

```
update-alternatives --query gcc
Name: gcc
Link: /usr/bin/gcc
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/gcc-5
Value: /usr/bin/gcc-5

Alternative: /usr/bin/gcc-5
Priority: 20

Alternative: /usr/bin/gcc-7
Priority: 10
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: yep, you need gcc 7.1: https://godbolt.org/z/eshhGeGMd, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017

Comment: I guess you didn't install gcc/libstdc++ correctly

Comment: @AlanBirtles Is this the right way to add the compiler? How to install correctly? How to set it default?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Mr. Alan please give a way to prioritize this compilers. And answer the question let me select it is correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok lastly I did able to build the code.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 20
```

First these commands to prioritize the compiler versions it worked

Answer (score 0):

'std::scoped_lock' is only available from C++17 onwards